# How to 'code collapse' wiki syntax on Notepad++ (or any other text editor)?

Tags: notepad++, syntax, mediawiki

I'm familiar with Notepad++'s code collapse for certain programming languages but recently I've been working with a plain text file that uses with Wiki syntax. For example:

```
==Heading1==
Content
===Heading2===
Content
===Heading3===
Content
==Heading1.1==
```

into (when I collapse Heading1):

```
==Heading1==
==Heading1.1==
```

I want to be able to collapse these headings and all their contents down at different levels, much like how Notepad++ can collapse tags in HTML, hiding all other tags inside it. I think that's as clear as I explain it any suggestions?

Comment: from your example, it looks like Heading1 and Heading1.1 are at the same level (with ==) while Heading2 and Heading3 are at another level (with ===)

Comment: Yeah, basically I want it to collapse until next heading with same level.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved in SynWrite editor. It has complex user-definable lexers (editor is built-in) in which you can create rules such as:

- `"from = to next ="`
- `"from == to next =="`

I won't describe how to create lexers for wiki syntax, it's not simple...

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++ it is possible to create a new User Defined Language. You can do so by selecting

```
View->User Define Dialog
```

Choose `"Folder & Default"` tab. This tab control the style of the default text (text that has no special attributes or meaning) and the keywords that control the folding. A keyword in the Folder Open group will trigger a new Fold group that can be expanded and collapsed. A keyword in the Folder Close group will close any opened group.
This explanation (and more..) is available at [npp-community documentation](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/languages/user-defined-languages)

Comment: The Folder collapsing syntax in User-Defined Language is rather primitive and works by identifying particular strings for the open and close. I doubt it can actually count the number of "=".