# Foldable/collapsable notepad++ markdown syntax

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting, markdown, multimarkdown

I am using Notepad++ for writing texts using Markdown syntax.

I know there exists at least one Notepad++ style file to hightlight Markdows texts (see [MultiMarkdown in Notepad ++](https://superuser.com/questions/525037/multimarkdown-in-notepad) and https://github.com/thomsmits/markdown_npp).

But I am interested in one new feature: I would like sections, subsections, subsubsections, etc. that I define with Markdown syntax to be recognized by the editor as collapsible or foldable and unfoldable, like it happens when coding in C++ or whatever.

How can I do that in Notepad++? I am not an expert in Notepad++ style files, but it does not seem too complicated. Maybe if someone gives me a hint, I could try it by myself...

EDIT: I've also seen this question: [How to 'code collapse' wiki syntax on Notepad++ (or any other text editor)?](https://superuser.com/questions/266931/how-to-code-collapse-wiki-syntax-on-notepad-or-any-other-text-editor), but I would like if there are other means to get what I want.

EDIT: I've posted a more general question regarding the same subject, here:

[Editor of txt files for Windows with syntax highlight and foldable/collapsible sections for Markdown](https://superuser.com/questions/563389/editor-of-txt-files-for-windows-with-syntax-highlight-and-foldable-collapsible-s)

Maybe now I should *close* this question, shouldn't I??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's currently not possible in Notepad++, because it's based on the Scintilla editing component, which does not support it.

And apparently the lead developer is not planning to work on this feature, though presumably this doesn't mean other developers couldn't submit code for it.

```
#971 codefolding for markdown  
itcould be possible to fold markdown at:
    headings (##)
    lists
    quotes
needed since January 25, 2010
```

---

```
Since I don't use markdown, I won't be working on this.
Neil Hodgson
2013-01-15
```

http://sourceforge.net/p/scintilla/feature-requests/971/

Comment: Even in the newest versions of Npp, user defined language folding doesn't work for even more standard coding syntax. I put a great deal of effort and experimentation into folding on headings and completely failed. When I tried `<StartFold>` and `<EndFold>` as a test on 8.1.1 just now, it also did not work.