# Editor of txt files for Windows with syntax highlight and foldable/collapsible sections for Markdown

Tags: vim, notepad++, text-editors, syntax-highlighting, markdown

I asked [the same for Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/563270/foldable-collapsable-notepad-markdown-syntax), but in fact I don't mind changing of software.

I am interested in managing txt files that contain Markdown. I would like to find an editor of txt files for Windows that is able to highlight Markdown syntax and, what is more important, to collapse on headings, etc.

I am flexible about the Markdown *flavour*, I mean, I don't mind if it is strict Markdown or Multimarkdown, etc.

The problem is I've never been really interested in txt editor. I actually use Notepad++, but don't know many *tricks*.

Now I am considering the possibility of using txt files for keeping some kind of information, and it would be great if I could find a way of collapse sections defined by using Markdown. My goal behind all this is being more productive, of course.

I am not sure if maybe Vim or other similar programs can be helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody correct me if I'm mistaken, but I believe that Sublime Text 2 does this (you may need to install a plugin for Markdown).  Code Folding definitely works in all languages in Sublime though.

[Sublime Code Folding](http://wesbos.com/sublime-text-code-folding/)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it seems that you are right. Some helpful links I've just discovered: http://www.macdrifter.com/2012/08/sublime-text-smartmarkdown-plugin.html , http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=7746

Comment: A really neat trick is I have this Markdown viewer for Mac called Marked and when I'm editing Markdown in Sublime, I can just 'Build' and it will preview what I'm working on in Marked.

Answer (score 2):

With [this folding plugin](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-markdown-folding), you can collapse Markdown headings; syntax highlighting works out of the box with Vim 7.3.

The great thing about Vim is its customizability; with a little bit of effort, you can influence the folding any way you want, or create a custom command to create a separate table of contents (in the *quickfix window*). On the other hand, be prepared for a steep initial learning curve, as it's a special and very powerful editor. (You can initially remedy this with *easy Vim* mode (`evim` or `gvim -e`), but I don't think many people will stay in that mode for long, as it's like training wheels.)

Comment: Thank you! It is an acceptable answer, but I am going to try with Sublime Text.